# How to dynamically create widgets without specific class instantiation in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create dynamically a certain amount of widgets, and then be able to modify them.

For example, I need some Checkboxes :

```py
# Class level lists to store the CheckButtons and their values
self.checkbutton_list = []
self.checkbutton_values_list = []

# With self.amount_of_widgets an integer
for i in range(0, self.amount_of_widgets):
    # We create the value of the current CheckButton, default is 0
    self.checkbutton_values_list.append(IntVar())
    # We create the CheckButton and append it to our list
    self.checkbutton_list.append(Checkbutton(self.canvasR, 
                                     text="rtest : " + str(i),
                                     variable=self.checkbutton_values_list[i],
                                     onvalue=1,
                                     offvalue=0,
                                     height=1,
                                     width=10))
    # As there is a lot of CheckButtons, they have to be browsable inside the canvas 
    # named canvasR, which has a scrollbar. To browse the created CheckButtons in the 
    # canva, we need to use the create_window function :
    self.canvasR.create_window(x, y, window=self.comp_checkbutton_list[i])
    y = y + 100
```

This generation works well, and I am able, to create all the desired widgets at their desired positions, and have them stored into the dedicated lists. For example I do something similar to create blank images ( I want to update those images later ) :

```py
for i in range(0, self.amount_of_widgets):
    # With default photo a PhotoImage object stored at class level
    self.photo_list.append(self.default_photo)
    self.photo_area_list.append(self.canvasR.create_image(x, y, 
                                     image=self.photo_list[i], 
                                     anchor=NW))
    y = y + 100
```

The issue is I fail to update the created widgets, if I try to call `.itemconfig()` like in the following code, I am getting a  **_tkinter.TclError: invalid boolean operator in tag search expression** :

```py
for i in range(0, self.max_image_displayed):
    self.canvasR.itemconfig(self.checkbutton_list[i], fill='black', text='')
```

I understand that it may not work because each widget does not specifically exist for the main class, because they have not been explicitly created inside the class. Only the list storing them does exist in this scope.

But I am not going to declare thousands of CheckBoxes or Images fields, one by one, by hand in my code like :

```py
self.area1 = self.canvasR.create_image(0, 0, image=self.photoimage1, anchor=NW)
self.area_list.append(self.area1)
self.area2 = self.canvasR.create_image(0, 100, image=self.photoimage2, anchor=NW)
self.area_list.append(self.area2)
# ...
self.area9999 = self.canvasR.create_image(0, 0, image=self.photoimage999, anchor=NW)
self.area_list.append(self.area9999)
```

What could I do?

Comment: Do you want to update the widgets in the lists?

Comment: ***"_tkinter.TclError: invalid ... in tag search"***: You have to use the returned `iid` value from `.create_window(...` instead of the `.append(Checkbutton(...` reference. Read up on [Tkinter.Canvas.itemconfig-method](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.itemconfig-method)

Comment: @DYD Yes i wish to update the widgets in the lists. For example in the code I showed, i was trying to change the value of the text attribute of the CheckButtons.

Comment: @stovfl So you mean i should have a list of the ```iid``` returned by each ```create_window()``` call, and use this identifier in the ```itenconfig()``` call ? Would this give me access to the CheckButtons i want to edit ?

Comment: @stovfl I tried what you recommended, but it does not give me access to the corresponding checkbutton, but to the frame containing it, created by the ```create_window()``` call. How can i access the checkbutton of the frame ?

Comment: ***"How can i access the checkbutton"***: `window = .itemcget(iid, 'window') ; button = .nametowidget(window)`

Comment: Should `self.checkbutton_list[i].config(...)` be used instead?

Answer (score 1):

> The issue is I fail to update the created widgets, if I try to call .itemconfig() like in the following code, i am getting a _tkinter.TclError: invalid boolean operator in tag search expression

When you call `self.canvasR.itemconfig`, the first argument needs to be identifier of an individual item on the canvas, or a tag. However, you're passing in `self.defaultPhoto` which is definitely not an item identifier or a tag.

In other words, what you pass to `itemconfig` should be the same as what is returned by `self.canvasR.create_image(...)` rather than the image itself, if your goal is to modify the canvas item created by `create_image`.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I may have a misunderstanding with your answer but if i use what is returned bay ```self.canvasR.create_image(...)``` as the target of my ```itemconfig()``` call, it would allow me to modify the window object, and not the check button contained inside the window doesn't it ?

Comment: @drheinrich940 It would allow you to modify the item on the canvas that was created when you called `create_image`.

Comment: But, as ```create_image``` creates a frame in the canva to store what was fed to the window parameter, it allows me only to access the created frame, and not the CheckButton inside the frame

Comment: @drheinrich940: your words don't make a lot of sense. `create_image` doesn't create a frame. Like the name implies, it adds an image to a canvas. The object it creates is a canvas item, not a widget. `create_window` also doesn't create a frame. It draws a widget on the canvas, but it doesn't create a frame (in the sense of a `Frame` widget).

Comment: I am deeply sorry, I was confusing ```canva.create_window()``` and ```canva.create_image()```. You are right, i should be able to modify the image with the generated id.